# Geometry problem involving orthocentre and midpoint of sides.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> Let $AA_1, BB_1, CC_1$ be the altitudes of $\Delta ABC$ and let $AB \neq BC$. If $M$ is midpoint of $BC$, $H$ the orthocentre of $\Delta ABC$ and $D$ the intersection of $BC$ and $B_1C_1$, prove that $DH \perp AM$

I was trying to come up with a pure geometric proof but haven't got far. These are the following approaches I have come up with:-

- The given conclusion is equivalent to the fact that $H$ is the orthocentre of $\Delta AMD$ which is equivalent to $AD \perp HM$
- The only viable way I could think of to use the fact that $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ is to consider the nine-point circle of $\Delta ABC$. This coupled with the fact that $D$ lies on the common chord (radical axis) of the nine point circle and the diametric circle of $AH$ might be helpful.
- I could also see a lot of perpendicular lines in the figure. This might point to an application of Simson's Theorem.

I would like some hints on how to approach the problem. If possible, please try to provide hints that build upon the above approaches.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $X$ be the intersection of $AM$ and $DH$.

The circumcircle $\Gamma_A$ of $B_1 C_1 H$ goes through $A$ since $\widehat{HC_1 A}=\widehat{HB_1 A}$. Its center is the midpoint of $AH$. In a similar way, the circumcircle $\Gamma_{A'}$ of $BCH$ goes through $A'$, i.e. the symmetric of $A$ with respect to $M$. Since $BCB_1 C_1$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $D$ belongs to the radical axis of $\Gamma_A$ and $\Gamma_{A'}$, that is perpendicular to the line joining the centre of $\Gamma_A$ with the centre of $\Gamma_{A'}$. We know where these centres lie (at the midpoints of $HA$ and $HA'$), hence we know that $DH\perp AM$. 
In particular, $X=DH\cap AM$ lies both on $\Gamma_A$ and on $\Gamma_{A'}$.

Comment: I don't see how you deduce $DH\perp AM$. Also, where is the center of $\Gamma_{A'}$?

Comment: @Wojowu: the radical axis is perpendicular to the line through the centres. The centres lie at the midpoint of $HA$ and at the midpoint of $HA'$, hence by joining them we get a line that is parallel to $AA'$, i.e. to $AM$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I see it.

Comment: I think you forgot to define point $A'$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Gerard: $A'$ is the symmetric of $A$ with respect to $M$.

Comment: What was your motivation for considering the circumcircle of $BCH$?

Comment: @Gerard: I tried to attack the problem by checking if $DH$ was the radical axis of something. Luckily, it was.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses [reciprocation with respect to a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) and a degenerated version of [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem).

LEMMA: Suppose points $A,B,C,D$ lie on a circle in this order. Let $AC,BD$ intersect at $G$, $AB,CD$ at $F$ and $AD,BC$ at $E$. Then line $EF$ is the polar of $G$ with respect to this circle.

PROOF: Using duality, it is enough to show that $G$ lies on polars of $E$ and $F$. I will show this for $F$ only.

Let tangents to the circle at $A,B$ intersect at $H$ and tangents at $C,D$ at $I$. It's easy to see that line $AB$ is the polar of $H$ and $CD$ is the polar of $I$. Since these polars intersect at $F$, by duality the polar of $F$ passes through $H,I$. So it's enough to show that $E,G,H,I$ are collinear.

By using Pascal's theorem on (degenerate) hexagon $AACBBD$ gives us that $E,G,H$ are collinear. Hexagon $CCADDB$ gives that $I,G,E$ are collinear. This is what we wanted, and this ends proof of the lemma.

[image]

Applying this lemma to the circle passing through $BCB_1C_1$ we get that the polar line of $H$ is $AD$, hence $AD$ is perpendicular to the line through $H$ and the center of considered circle (by definition of polar line). But the center is $M$, so $HM\perp AD$, which ends the proof as you have remarked.

Comment: Nice solution, but quite an overkill, don't you think?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yeah, that's true. I've noticed that line $AD$ will have to be the polar of $H$ with respect to circle $BCB_1C_1$, and that this will solve the problem, which is why I focused on proving that (which is how I could've missed an easier solution, like yours).